# How to get execution date in airflow date as a variable?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to be able to test a DAG behaviour by running a backfill.
I have a BranchPythonOperator that uses the date of the dag run to decide about which branch to go.

I use

> datetime.today()

But what i'm looking for is the execution date

```
today = datetime.today()

def check_working_day(today, **kwargs):
    cal = France()
    print(today)
    if (cal.is_working_day(today)):
        return "is_file_available"
    else:
        return "not_holiday"
```

> today = datetime.today()

should be something like

> today = execution_date_of_the_dag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `ds` or `execution_date` which are available in **kwargs. Have a look into the [macro reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html) and the [PythonOperator Documentation.](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/operator/python.html)

This should work:

```
def check_working_day(execution_date, **kwargs):
    cal = France()
    print(execution_date)
    if (cal.is_working_day(execution_date)):
        return "is_file_available"
    else:
        return "not_holiday"
```

You just need to make sure your PythonOperator has set `provide_context=True`.

Comment: `execution_date` seems to be deprecated: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html, use `ds` or `ts` instead